# Vector-Java equivalent in PHP?

Tags: java, php

Is there a:

1> Vector(Java) class
2> ListIterator
3> Single Linkedlist

equivalent available in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Any PHP array can be considered and used as a Vector (since by definition Vector is just an array that can grow in size and PHP doesn't require to specify array size). As java documents it,

```
public class Vector 
extends AbstractList
implements List, RandomAccess, Cloneable, Serializable
```

PHP array fulfills all there requirements.

2) There is an [Iterator](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) if you insist on it, but in general it is much more common to use loops for array traversing (just like you don't really iterate arrays in Java with Iterator, do you?)

3) There is no list implementations in PHP in general (well, I bet internally arrays are implemented as a list/hashmap, but that's only internally). You can go with one of two options. Either use array (do you see a pattern here - arrays FTW!) if you are only interested in sequential ordering of items (you get random access as a bonus), or you can implement your own completely-OO list with 2 small classes (I'd call them `List` and `ListCell`)

Addition to part 3: Don't worry about insertions or deletions in the middle of the list, as those may be achieved with [array_slice](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [array_splice](http://lt.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php). Insertion and deletion may not be O(1) timewise, but since in the list you would also need O(n) time for locating the place to insert in the list, I thing the options are comparable.

Comment: But in case of ListIterator + Linkedlist, I can at least add/remove elements from LinkedList through the Iterator. How can I achieve the same in PHP using arrays? If I am not wrong, adding elements in ListIterator would append in linkelist as opposed to overwriting the element at the position in PHP

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you are reffering to, but in PHP you can `unset($array[$idx])` - removes element from any position without leaving a gap; `$array[] = $val` -- append to the end (there is also `array_unshift()` for prepending); `array_splice()` for insertion in the middle.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is:

1. Array
2. Array
3. Array

PHP arrays are powerful constructs that are can be used as arrays, lists, hashes, queues and stacks (which may all be different types in other languages) all at the same time.

If you need more control over the behaviour of an array-like construct, there are interfaces and classes in [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) you can implenet/use/extend.

Comment: I wouldn't call PHP arrays exactly "powerful" but otherwise I agree with what you said.

Comment: But in case of ListIterator + Linkedlist, I can at least add/remove elements from LinkedList through the Iterator. How can I achieve the same in PHP using arrays? If I am not wrong, adding elements in ListIterator would append in linkelist as opposed to overwriting the element at the position in PHP

Comment: @Esko -- a single data type that can be used as an array, as a dictionary, as a stack, or as a queue. Its trivially easy to represent trees, linked lists using php arrays. Id say it was a pretty powerful construct.

Comment: @darkie15, Not quiet sure exactly what you're trying to do, I think you might be after array_splice/array_slice. PHPs array functions can manipulate arrays in any way you would likely ever need. If you have a more specific question you might want to ask it.

Comment: @James The word "powerful" comes with the intent of being something explicitly designed and my experience with PHP says that nothing in it has never actually been designed, at least not by competent people. I do agree that it's flexible and I can agree that it's relatively simple to do whatever kind of data structures with it, but that doesn't mean that *"array as everything"* is a good design.