# Does PHP have Different Implementations of Lists

Tags: java, php, list

I'm more of a java guy, and I was talking with a PHP guy. He said that PHP pretty much only uses arrays for lists. Googling for different concrete implementations of lists in PHP was unfruitful for me.

Being that there are different advantages of concrete implementations of lists in java, I found this hard to believe that there wasn't something similar in PHP.

Is there PHP equivalents of the following: `Singly Linked List`, `ArrayList` (yes, the array of course), `Vector`, and `Stack`?

Comment: PHP's arrays would handle the last three natively, I believe. [Here's](https://gist.github.com/zachflower/031e2f30f07e6c286ab8) a singly linked list implementation in PHP.

Comment: Consider reading this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6248012/4813010

Comment: PHP has implementations of DoublyLinkedLists, Stacks, Queues, Heaps and various other datastructures in [SPL](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php) which has been a part of PHP core since version 5.3.0... sadly, many PHP devs seem oblivious to the existence of these datastructures, and will try to replicate them all using standard PHP arrays

Comment: @MarkBaker isn't that worthy of being an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above the basic PHP datatypes most people would use Array as Java lists, consider the available types that most PHP developers know of

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php

Array is the one that mostly does what you want. However the Standard PHP Libary (SPL) do have some data-structures that might interest you, mostly the SplDoublyLinkedList.

You might also want to note that it provides SplFixedArray to handle the issue PHP can have when you work with arrays (PHP have many adventages memory use is not one of them, see https://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html)